# LLVM store array

Tags: arrays, copy, llvm, clone

Can I use the ***store*** llvm instruction to copy/clone an array?

I'm interested to represent the following C code in LLVM, but I wouldn't like use the memcpy function, because I need know the size of the array.

```
char larray3[3] = {[0 ... 2] = 10};
char larray4;
memcpy(larray4, larray3, strlen(larray3)+1);
```

I would like copy/clone an array using something similar to the following LLVM code:

```
store <type> %larray3, <type> %larray4
```

Is it possible for the multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. LLVM IR has [array type](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#array-type) for this. For your code, `larray3` could  be represented as  `[3 x i8]`. It means an array with 3 elements, each element type is `i8`.

Comment: It works using the constants, for example:

`store [3 x i8] [i8 1, i8 2, i8 3], [3 x i8]* %larray4`

But I don't know how to use a variable replacing the constant.

Look the following code:

;;What type I can put here (in the next line)? 

`store <??> %larray3, [3 x i8]* %larray4`